# How to stop displaying a loading GIF after downloading an Excel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem when I try to stop displaying a loading GIF, after I download an excel file.

I excecute a method from client side that shows a loading GIF, and then I serch information to export it to an Excel.

The problem is, when the file is downloaded, I try to stop displaying the GIF from code behind with a ScriptManager like in the code...

```
private void hideLoading()
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "loadingModal", "hideModalLoading();", true);            
}
```

But this doesn’t work I think its because the response has already been sent to download the file. 
(I'm not sure...)

The problem...
[image]

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image.

Comment: I would consider whether it's really necessary to show the waiting gif in the first place.  You are returning a file so reading the response headers would be necessary to know that the file has been returned and has started to download.... so wait until you "getResponseHeader("Content-Type");"